# How can i set svg images as button images in ios sdk?

Tags: ios, image, svg

I want to set svg(scalable vector graphics) images as button images in ipad.so that i can use same image for ipad2,ipad3

Comment: user1285498: please use this question, as your duplicate question should be closed in due course. As per my comments on your other question, can you tell us here what you have tried online to answer this question? Have you checked the official iOS docs?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [third party](https://github.com/jacekmigacz/ObjectiveSVG) libraries. Quartz is not aware of SVG.

Comment: is gradients are supported in this package objective svg

Comment: no. try something else on [GitHub](https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=svg&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Everything&language=Objective-C)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use https://github.com/arielelkin/PocketSVG

```
//Step 1
CGPathRef myPath = [PocketSVG pathFromSVGFileNamed:@"icon_convidar"];

//Step 2: To display it on screen, you can create a CAShapeLayer
//and set myPath as its path property:
CAShapeLayer *shape = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shape.path = myPath;


//Step 3: Fiddle with it using CAShapeLayer's properties:
shape.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
shape.lineWidth = 4;

//Step 4: Display it!
[self.btnConvidar.layer addSublayer:shape];
```